# Undecorated JDialog border

Tags: java, swing, border, jdialog, uimanager

I have a question regarding the border around an undecorated `JDialog` using the `Metal L&F`.

Look at this picture to see the border that is on this window:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to either get rid of or change the color of the blue border around the very outside of the `JDialog`. I looked at the UI defaults for the `Look & Feel` but I wasn't able to come up with any that worked for this.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to get rid of that border?

Thanks!

Comment: Can my answer in you another question http://stackoverflow.com/a/32752359/5370194 help you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to change the `Border` of the root pane:

```
getRootPane().
   setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED) );
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get rid of it you can use

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
```

To change the look of it from the Java style to the windows style you can use

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Comment: This does not do what I want it to. I need the title bar to stay at the top while also having the frame undecorated. The only way to do this is to use the metal look & feel. Setting the window decoration style to none gets rid of the title bar at the top.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
((JPanel)getContentPane()).setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
```

[image]

---

You can try to do this in order to change the most outsude border:

```
getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
```

Is this what you want to do?

Comment: `getRootPane()` is inside border - author pointed for outside border of undecorated JDialog