# Color of JOptionPane border

Tags: java, swing, border, joptionpane, look-and-feel

How might I go about changing the color of a `JOptionPane's border`?

Here is a screenshot of the border I am talking about:

[image]

That blue border is what I am trying to get rid of.

I tried to set  `UIManager.put("OptionPane.border", new BorderFactory...)`for LookAndFeel but that changed the inside border, not the outermost one.

I need to get rid of that blue border.

Any ideas?

-Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the `JOptionPane API`. It shows you how to create a JOption pane manually so that you have access to the JDialog. Once you have the JDialog you can remove the Border the same way you did in your last question:

[Undecorated JDialog border](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17413658/131872)

Comment: Perfect, didn't know that was possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have research on it these days, finally I found this code may help you!

```
UIManager.put("RootPane.frameBorder", new LineBorder(Color.red));
UIManager.put("RootPane.dialogBorder", new LineBorder(Color.red));    
UIManager.put("RootPane.errorDialogBorder", new LineBorder(Color.red));
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation to the code? It might help OP or future users more that way.

Comment: I read the source code of alloy.jar whose JOptionPane border color is always red for error or yellow for warning. These codes tell us how to change the color of it.

Answer (score 0):

In LaF section there is the initialization of `ShadowPopupBorder` which used for tooltips, popups, and modal dialogs borders. So check if it is used around your software